# Increase draw area for fragment shader

Tags: opengl, libgdx, glsl

I'm working with libgdx and I want to draw an outline around an image via this shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

// The inverse of the viewport dimensions along X and Y
uniform vec2 u_viewportInverse;

// Color of the outline
uniform vec3 u_color;

// Thickness of the outline
uniform float u_offset;

// Step to check for neighbors
uniform float u_step;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

#define ALPHA_VALUE_BORDER 0.5

void main() {
   vec2 T = v_texCoords.xy;

   float alpha = 0.0;
   bool allin = true;
   for( float ix = -u_offset; ix < u_offset; ix += u_step )
   {
      for( float iy = -u_offset; iy < u_offset; iy += u_step )
       {
          float newAlpha = texture2D(u_texture, T + vec2(ix, iy) * u_viewportInverse).a;
          allin = allin && newAlpha > ALPHA_VALUE_BORDER;
          if (newAlpha > ALPHA_VALUE_BORDER && newAlpha >= alpha)
          {
             alpha = newAlpha;
          }
      }
   }
   if (allin)
   {
      alpha = 0.0;
   }

   gl_FragColor = vec4(u_color,alpha);
}
```

*Source: http://www.allpiper.com/2d-selection-outline-shader-in-libgdx/*

```
batch.setShader(Assets.shaderOutline);
Assets.shaderOutline.setUniformf("u_viewportInverse", new Vector2(1f / Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 1f / Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
Assets.shaderOutline.setUniformf("u_offset", 20);
Assets.shaderOutline.setUniformf("u_step", Math.min(1f, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 70f));
Assets.shaderOutline.setUniformf("u_color", new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
flagellumSprite.draw(batch);
box2DSprite.draw(batch, tempVec2.x, tempVec2.y, width(fixtureBody), height(fixtureBody), cachedPos.getAngle());
batch.setShader(null);
flagellumSprite.draw(batch);
box2DSprite.draw(batch, tempVec2.x, tempVec2.y, width(fixtureBody), height(fixtureBody), cachedPos.getAngle());
```

Works fine so far, except that the texture image is only as big as the circle is, so the fragment shader is only applied in the exact rectangle around the circle. This results in an image like this (The circle body and the flagellums are separate textures):

[image: without shader][image: shader applied]

So is there an easy way to increase the area where the fragment shader is applied? I thought something like a vertex shader, that scales the positions up, and the texture down (by the same ratio). But I didn't manage to implement that. Other tipps are also greatly appreciated.

I could of course just add a margin to the textures, but that can't be the best solution, or is it?

Comment: Rescaling the sprite and adding margin could be the best and simplest solution.

Comment: You just need to add margins to your sprite. A vertex shader could only do this if you wrote your own alternative to SpriteBatch that has a sprite center attribute for the vertices.